# Can I use a shell command output as an option parameter in Doxygen?

Tags: linux, doxygen

I wonder if it's possible to use a shell command output as an option parameter in Doxygen config file. For example, you need to set 'PROJECT_NAME' option. I already have a README file and the first line of this file is the name of the project. I could do '`head -1 ../README`' in Doxygen config instead of copying the same few words all over the place. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(PROJECT_NAME)` as the value for the `PROJECT_NAME` tag and set the environment variable to the right value before invoking doxygen. If you use bash, you can do:

```
PROJECT_NAME=`head -1 ../README` doxygen project.doxyfile
```

Which works nicely for me.